# Does BULK insert (SQL server) work only with external file?

Tags: sql-server

I want to bulk insert records from the SELECT query result but I think in SQL server we can only bulk insert from a file.
Is there a way where I can perform the bulk insert from SELECT query and which should also be faster as compared to bulk insert

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can just do `INSERT ... SELECT`

Comment: `BULK INSERT` from file is much faster. But you can do it from client, see `SqlBulkCopy` class in C#

Comment: See discussion on [minimal logging](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-empty-clustered)